# Error 0x80070005: Access Denied when first start Hyper-V in Windows 10 Pro

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-10

I'm trying to run Hyper-V on a freshly installed Windows 10 Pro (1709) on AMD FX 6350, 8 GB RAM.
Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management (vmms) starts properly but Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute) crashes with the error `Windows could not start the Hyper-V Host Compute Service on Local Computer. Error 0x80070005: Access is denied.`

In the log only meaningless message `The Hyper-V Host Compute Service service terminated with the following error: General access denied error`.

Googling finds a similar error when migrating or exporting virtual machines, but not the first time Hyper-V starts with no VMs are created.

Previously, this hardware was Windows 7 and Vmware Player worked fine. Now I want to try "native" virtualization.

By the way, exactly the same problem on the laptop on Intel i5-2430M.

Comment: Encountered exactly the same problem after installing the latest November Cumulative updates. Previously, Hyper-V and vmcompute launched fine on Fall Creators Update (1709). Naturally, disabling and enabling Hyper-V again doesn't help, nor is this a permissions problem with the Hyper-V user folder. Process Monitor also doesn't suggest any filesystem or registry permissions issue for vmcompute so far. Like you said, this is different from the issues posted on the internet.

Comment: The latest Cumulative update was released November 30th, and I haven't yet confirmed if that's the one causing the issue (will be reverting later today and editing the post with new information). If you have it installed, might try to revert as well. The two Cumulative Updates installed for me are KB4051963 and KB4048955, with KB4051963 being the Nov 30 one.

Comment: KB4048955 there wasn't in my system. But KB4051963 there was and it uninstalling doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [sf]. This is not a forum; it is not necessary to use things like "SOLVED" or "EDIT" to mark a question. You may mark a question as solved by ticking the mark next to the answer which solved your problem (as you have already done).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is known to be caused by disabling Windows `Control flow guard (CFG)`.

To turn this back on:

- Search for and open `Windows Defender Security Center` on the start menu.
- Go into `App & browser control`:
  [image: Windows Defender Security Center]
- Scroll to the bottom and click on `Exploit protection settings`:
  [image: App & browser control]
- Ensure that `Control flow guard (CFG)` is set to `On by default`:
  [image: Exploit protection settings]

This morning my Hyper-V was working, then this evening it wasn't. Disabling CFG was the only noteworthy activity I had done on Windows aside from regular application use. After re-enabling the feature, Hyper-V was working again for me.

I disabled the feature in the first place due to [an issue with Windows 10 build 1709](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136952/mfc-ribbon-slow-on-first-loadshow.html) which is severely impacting my TortoiseGit performance in that the diff tool takes about 5 seconds to open.

Another users [comment on that page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/136952/mfc-ribbon-slow-on-first-loadshow.html#reply-169325) reports the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed issues I had starting docker because hyper-v wouldn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Control Flow Guard might be the issue, Control Flow Guard needs to be enabled for the Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute.exe) and Virtual Machine Worker Process (VMWP.exe) for Hyper-V's required services (Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management[vmms.exe] & Hyper-V Host Compute Service[vmcompute.exe]) to work.

If you have Control Flow Guard enabled for your whole system, you need to disable the override (that disables Control Flow Guard) in Windows Security settings (SecHealthUI.exe) or if you have Control Flow Guard disabled for your whole system, you need to enable the override for vmcompute.exe & VMWP.exe.

Source:
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Nested-Virtualization/hyper-v-crashing/td-p/522812